# Can I use a / rather than \ to as a path separator in csc parameters?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, csc

I am using `csc` directly to compile a C# application, but when I specify the source files as `src/main.cs` it fails.

I have realised that I need to make them `src\main.cs"` Now, I am wondering if it possible to specify a source file with a `/` rather than a `\`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do that? `\ ` is the preferred path separator on windows, even if `/` is possible in most places too.

Comment: As you found yourself: it is not possible... Is this a real question or rather a statement?

Comment: So what compile error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows file path separator is `\` so that is what you have to use. It would be the same for all other programs as this is defined at the OS level.

While CodeInChaos mentioned that certain Windows APIs accept `/` as a path seperator this will not work with a command line application such as csc.exe because it uses the `/` for specifying options. Supporting forward slash for file paths as well would cause ambiguity.

Comment: You can use `/` most of the time too on windows. So it is an application issue.

Comment: so, is the answer "yes, possible", "no, impossible" or "I don't know"?

Comment: While some OS APIs might allow `/` a lot of applications do not. Csc.exe seems to be one of those that don't. Considering that the back slash is accepted universally on Windows, that's the path seperator character you should be using.

Comment: Yeah, I'm so used to using "-" on linux to specify flags I completely overlooked that because you use "/" in windows, you can not specify a path with / in it, thanks for the help.